# Why % is showing in the first load of my website

Tags: html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JVei.png)

Why this % is showing inside the email, it should Please enter your email

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 0):

The code look something like this:

```js
<form method="post">
<input type="email" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email" />
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```html
<html>
<body>
<input required type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" />
<input required type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Clear your browser history then try again